# Function to delete selective row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question.

I want to delete row in a dataframe but my function is deleting the wrong row. Sorry it is not the best code as I just start and the constant print are for my fault search.

```
#Reduce by a factor
    firstrow = int(in_csv.loc[in_csv.index[0]].name)
    lastrow = int(in_csv.loc[in_csv.index[-1]].name)

    for i in range (firstrow, lastrow+1):
        division = (i/reduce_factor)
        print (str(i) + " is " + str(division))
        print ("Division" + str(math.modf(division)))
        if ((math.modf(division)[0]) != 0):
            print (i)
            print (in_csv.iloc[i])
            i_drop = in_csv.loc[in_csv.index[i]].name
            print ("drop: " + str(i_drop))
            in_csv.drop([i], inplace=True)
```

The results is the following

```
5 is 2.5
Division(0.5, 2.0)
5
Time             5/11/20 12:01:32 AM
number                     1

Name: 7, dtype: object
drop: 7
```

For the calulation for row 5 it is dropping row 7, for row 7 it is 10, for row 3 it is row 4, for row 1 it is correct. So for every dropped row the fault is increasing by one row.

What is my fault?

Comment: Welcome, @Lukas! Here are some guidelines for making good posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In particular, make sure to post the input and expected output so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you should gather indices of rows to drop and perform the drop
**after** the loop.

But to be sure I have to know the content of your DataFrame, at least some
initial part of it, including the rows in question.